# Can you load resource directories instead of per file

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I have a directory with a lot of different resource files, I want to import them all at the same time instead of per file.

I dont want to import all of them 1 by 1 so I hope there is a way to import them per directory

Is it possible to do it like this?

```
Resource          resources
```

Instead of

```
Resource          resources/renter/auth.robot
Resource          resources/renter/credentials.robot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - no, you can't do that. The framework doesn't support loading all modules in a directory (`Resource    dir_name`), nor wildcard imports (`Resource    dir_name/*`).

If you don't want to have the imports repeated, you can make a resource file that imports all others (`all_imports.robot`), and then import just that in your suites. Thus if there is an extra/new resource you want everywhere, you add it in just one place - that file.

Comment: Is there a way that I write a library or something that can import everything for me?

Comment: You should be able to - a simple python function, that will get the files in a directory passed as an argument, and will import them as resources with the `import_resource()` method in the `BuiltIn` class of `robot.libraries.BuiltIn`.

Comment: Is there a tutorial of how to do that? I never worked with python and Im really new to Robot Framework

Comment: Then I would suggest to go with my current answer; it fulfills your need, while still giving you control and visibility what happens and how it works. If I (or someone else) write that function/library for you, it will be used as-is, and any side effects, bugs or future maintenance will be hard to implement by yourself.

Comment: Your boss is not a factor in this question. The question simply states if something is possible. The short answer is: "No". An alternative is provided by @TodorMinakov and this is rather common practice to implement.